# Why I encountered error on MySQL 'UPDATE' command?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-update, mariadb

currently my Class Diagram looks like this:

[image]

and I would like to Update **ALL** my product details *(prodName, prodDesc, prodCategory, prodDesc,manufacturer, supplier, stockLevel, reorderLevel, unitPrice)* except prodID.

so I using this SQL query:

```
UPDATE Product
    SET prodName = @prodName,
        prodCategory = @prodCategory,
        prodDesc = @prodDesc,
        manufacturer = @manufacturer,
        supplier = @supplier,
        stockLevel = @stockLevel,
        reorderLevel = @reorderLevel,
        unitPrice = @unitPrice
FROM product a, supply_item b, supply c
WHERE a.prodID = @prodID AND
      @prodID = b.prodID AND
      b.supplyID = c.supplyID;
```

but it unable to works, is my query correct?

This is the section of my code

```
protected void editSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlConn);
        string sql = "UPDATE Product SET prodName = @prodName, prodCategory = @prodCategory, prodDesc = @prodDesc, manufacturer = @manufacturer, supplier = @supplier, stockLevel = @stockLevel, reorderLevel = @reorderLevel, unitPrice = @unitPrice FROM product a, supply_item b, supply c WHERE a.prodID = @prodID AND @prodID = b.prodID AND b.supplyID = c.supplyID;";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", txtProductName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodCategory", txtCategory.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodDesc", txtProductDesc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manufacturer", txtManufacturer.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier", txtSupplier.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockLevel", txtStockLvl.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reorderLevel", txtReorderLvl.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitPrice", txtPrice.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodID", txtProductID.Text); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Originally, I used this query,

```
"UPDATE Product SET prodName = @prodName, prodCategory = @prodCategory, prodDesc = @prodDesc, manufacturer = @manufacturer, supplier = @supplier, stockLevel = @stockLevel, reorderLevel = @reorderLevel, unitPrice = @unitPrice WHERE prodID = @prodID"
```

but it doesn't show any error, and I unable to update any values on my product
Any idea how to update my product?
Thanks

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `FROM` in the `UPDATE` statement.  And commas in the `FROM` clause are not recommended in *any* database.

Comment: With any SQL, try running it in the SQL tooling directly before trying it in C#.

Comment: Oh I see, then what should I used instead of `FROM` ?

Comment: One approach is to change your update statement into a select,  confirm you are getting the records you need back. Once you confirm that then modify the query to an update statement (keeping the were clause). https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/

Comment: Think about binding the values, not using @variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in MySQL would seem to be:

```
UPDATE product p JOIN
       supply_item si 
       ON p.prodId = si.prodId JOIN 
       supply s
       ON s.supplyID = si.supplyID;
    SET p.prodName = @prodName,
        p.prodCategory = @prodCategory,
        p.prodDesc = @prodDesc,
        p.manufacturer = @manufacturer,
        p.supplier = @supplier,
        p.stockLevel = @stockLevel,
        p.reorderLevel = @reorderLevel,
        p.unitPrice = @unitPrice
WHERE p.prodID = @prodID;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases (such as abbreviations for table names), not arbitrary letters.

Comment: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.prodId b.prodId JOINsupply sON s.supplyID = si.supplyID;SET p.prodName = 'H...' at line 1'`, but it displayed this kind of error.

Comment: Not if you use what Gordon posted. You seem to have grabbed and executed some arbitrary code.

Comment: @SHAOHONGLI . . . My code has no `a.prodid` in it, so it cannot produce that error.

Comment: Oh ya, my typing error. Thanks for the information!